# Create graphs by group using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm relatively new to using `ggplot2` in R and have been struggling with this for awhile. I have figured out how to get everything from one data frame on a graph (that is pretty easy...), and how to write a loop function to get each observation (`id` in the example below) onto their own graphs but not how to create separate graphs with multiple `id` per `group`, when the `id` and `group` can change each time I run the code. Here is some sample data and the output I am trying to produce.

```
x <- c(1,3,6,12,24,48,72,1,3,6,12,24,48,72,1,3,6,12,24,48,72,1,3,6,12,24,48,72)
y <- c(8,27,67,193,271,294,300,10,30,70,195,280,300,310,5,25,60,185,250,275,300,15,40,80,225,275,325,330)
group <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
id <- c(100,100,100,100,100,100,100,101,101,101,101,101,101,101,102,102,102,102,102,102,102,103,103,103,103,103,103,103)
df <- data.frame(x,y,group,id)
```

[image]

Similar questions were asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324160/arrange-ggplot-graphs-by-group) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135673/plotting-multiple-lines-based-on-grouping-with-geom-line) but I still can't figure out how to do what I need because I need separate graphs (not facets) by `group` with multiple `id` on the same graph.

Edit to add attempt -

```
l <- unique(df$group)
for(l in df$group){
  print(ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, color = id))+
    geom_line())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your desired result

1. Split your dataframe by `group` using e.g. `split`
2. Use `lapply` to loop over the list of splitted data frames to create your plots or if you want to add the group labels to the title you could loop over `names(df_split)`.

Note: I converted the `id` variable to factor. Also, you have to map `id` on the group aesthetic to get lines per group. However, as your x variable is a numeric there is actually no need for the `group` aesthetic.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df_split <- split(df, df$group)

lapply(df_split, function(df) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = id, color = factor(id))) +
    geom_line()
})
```

```
lapply(names(df_split), function(i) {
  ggplot(df_split[[i]], aes(x = x, y = y, group = id, color = factor(id))) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = paste("group =", i))
})
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

And even I if would recommend to use `lapply` the same could be achieved using a `for` loop like so:

```r
for (i in names(df_split)) {
  print(
    ggplot(df_split[[i]], aes(x = x, y = y, group = id, color = factor(id))) +
      geom_line() +
      labs(title = paste("group =", i))
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x= x, y=y, colour= factor(id))) + geom_line() + facet_grid(group ~ .)
```

[image]

Edit: OP clarifies in comments they want separate graphs, not faceting

```
# 1
ggplot2(df[df$group == 1,], aes(x= x, y=y, colour= factor(id))) + geom_line()
# 2
ggplot2(df[df$group == 2,], aes(x= x, y=y, colour= factor(id))) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you but I need separate graphs not facets

Comment: Then subset `df` and do two graphs

Comment: I know how to do that if I know what `id` are but I am trying to write a loop so I can use this for a routine weekly report

Comment: @yaynikkiprograms If your question doesn't reflect what you actually want to do, it's impossible to answer correctly. Kindly improve your question